# Help me with this integral.

Tags: integration

If possible, please explain explicitly. Thanks.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}(x-\mu)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}(x-\mu)^2dx~=~2\sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}dx~=~2\sqrt2~\sigma^3\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}t^2dt,$$ with $t=\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}$ . Now, notice that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}t^2dt=-\bigg[\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt\bigg]_{a=1}$ But the latter equals $\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}$ by a simple substitution $u=t\sqrt a$, see [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) for more details. Now, all you have to do is differentiate $\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}$ withy regards to *a*, add a minus sign in front of it, and then replace *a* with $1$. So, can you take it from here ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to give you the steps to get to the solution, but where I omit the constants because they're not important to get the idea.

1. To integrate $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^2 \mathrm{d}x$:

   Integrate by parts, grouping $e^{-x^2}x$ as one function and $x$ as the other.
2. To integrate $\displaystyle \int e^{-x^2} x \mathrm{d}x$:

   Use $u$-substitution with $u = x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $t=\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ and take into account that the integral to the left left and to the right of $\mu$ is the same due to symmetry (so it becomes twice the integral from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$). What you get is a Gamma function in the form
$$\Gamma(n)=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}{\,\rm d}t$$
with some extra constant factors.

Because $n$ is a half integer in this case, use

$$\Gamma(\tfrac12)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
and
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$$
to get the final answer.